# TeX Live installs Makefiles as documentation

Tags: texlive

On my TeX Live installation there are about 200 Makefiles installed in the `texmf-dist/doc` subtree. They, of course, hardly count as documentation. Even strangier their placement seems in light of that every TeX Live package also has a source archive, where (and only where) the Makefiles would normally go.

However, this doesn't seem to be an unnoticed mistake, as even `texdoc` knows enough about them to have an exception rule:

```
> texdoc -d impatient
. . .
texdoc debug-score: Start scoring /data/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/plain/impatient/Makefile
texdoc debug-score: Name used: impatient/makefile
texdoc debug-score: Start heuristic scoring with pattern: impatient
texdoc debug-score: New heuristic score: 1. Reason: subword match
texdoc debug-score: New heuristic score: 0.1. Reason: bad extension
texdoc debug-score: New heuristic score: 1.6. Reason: directory bonus
texdoc debug-score: Final heuristic score: 1.6
texdoc debug-score: Max pattern score: 1.6
texdoc debug-score: Adjust by -1000 from global pattern '/makefile'  <===
texdoc debug-score: Final score: -998.4
. . .
```

Why are the Makefiles placed in the documentation subtree?

Comment: Some of them are legitimately there, for instance `.../koma-script/doc/english/Makefile`. Other are there possibly by mistake or not very clear instructions of the package authors.

Comment: @egreg: That's in `texmf-dist/source/`, not `texmf-dist/doc`. But I agree: files like `texmf-dist/doc/context/manuals/reference/en/Makefile` belong into doc, not source.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Hmm. In this Makefile I see only instructions to make `contextref.pdf`. Why does it belong to `doc`? It's not documentation and has no use for the user.

Comment: @AndreyVihrov: It's the makefile for the documentation. `:-)`

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Now I actually did an `ls` in the directory you point out and saw a huge list of _source_ files instead of ready-to-use documentation. It seems that my definition of "documentation" differs much from the TeX Live's one.

Comment: @AndreyVihrov: Where would you put the source of the documentation?

Comment: @MartinSchröder: With the rest of the source files, leaving only final documentation files in `doc/`. After all, that's what is done with the run files — there are no `.dtx` alongside them, if we make an analogy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since the question deals with "impatient" as included in tex live, i asked the tex live coordinators.

the answer is simply that a) many packages (including impatient) are only doc and it would be a cause of confusion to move a file or two to the source/ subtree, because also b) there is no practical difference between source/ and doc/ .  the tex live maintainers don't worry about this, and nobody else should either.